# How do i search a word that contain specific characters from input command?

Tags: python-3.x

so, i have assingment from my course, it requires me to find a word (or more) from a list that contain a specific character from input.

lets say i have this list

```
word = ["eat", "drink", "yoga", "swim"]
```

and when i given input A, it should return me

```
["eat", "yoga"]
```

Comment: what is your input A ?

Comment: it can be A or anything the user want. if you input m, it will show you swim

Answer (score 3):

You can use list comprehension.

```
ch = input("enter character")
output = [w for w in word if ch.lower() in w]
```

You may want to add some checks on the input (e.g. input is a single character or not)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
list = ["eat", "drink", "yoga", "swim"]
reslst = []
alpa = input("enter character") #convert into lowercase
ch = alpa.lower()
for i in list:
#check if character is in string
    if ch in i:
        reslst.append(i)
print(reslst)
```